# ХОСТИНГ ДЛЯ ASP.NET + MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, хостинг, backend

Пишу дипломный проект с помощью ASP.NET MVC с интеграцией в проект базы данных на базе MS SQL Server. Все бы ничего, но руководитель сказал, что для успешной сдачи дипломного проекта необходимо сайт вывести в сеть.

Раньше выводил на хостинг только сайты-визитки, однако теперь в проекте появился Backend. Так вот, возникло пару вопросов:

1. **Что необходимо оформить/приобрести для публикации сайта на ASP.NET MVC в сеть?** Прочитал несколько статей и посмотрел несколько видео. Так как из-за санкций сейчас относительно проблематично приобрести хостинг с Windows Server, скорее всего прийдется делать все через Linux. Как я понимаю, необходимо приобрести хостинг, на котором будет запускаться мой сайт, а также домен, к которому хостинг будет привязан. Также видел способ публикации сайта в сеть с помощью контейнеров Docker, однако не очень понял, насколько это подойдет в ситуации, когда еще надо обращаться к базе данных.
2. **Как правильнее захостить базу данных и обращаться к ней из проекта?** Во всех туториалах, которые я смотрел или читал, база данных находится непосредственно в одной, назовем это "рабочей среде", с самим программным продуктом на ASP.NET MVC. Так вот, если покупать отдельно сервер для базы данных, к нему вероятно надо будет обращаться через строку подключения, находящуюся в appsettings.json. С удаленными БД ни разу не работал, только с API, на которые отправлялись запросы с помощью HttpClient, что в моем случае будет не очень удобным, так как использую Entity Framework для генерации моделей и файла контекста. **Если все же надо будет размещать БД не на одном хостинге с ASP, как к ней подключаться?** Также через строку подключения, но указывая адрес сервера удаленный, а не локальный?

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь и ссылки на какие-либо источники! Всем хорошего дня!

Comment: Во-первых, в вопросе должен быть один вопрос, а не два. Во-вторых, "правильного" ответа на оба вопроса нет, конкретное решение выбирается по конкретным потребностям и предпочтениям

Comment: Еще большой вопрос, ASP.NET это или ASP.NET Core. Со вторым +/- все нормально пройдет, а вот на развертывание первого на линуксах я бы посмотрел...

Comment: `ngrok` возьмите и в докер свой локальный пробросьте порт, или в чем там у вас все работает.